# When useridentity is updated will MFP also store the old useridentities

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I have an Android app that connects to MFP server. I am using adapter to create a useridentity. So to change the useridentity I have used the following code.

```
WL.Server.setActiveUser("AuthRealm", null);
WL.Server.setActiveUser("AuthRealm", userIdentity);
```

Now my question is if my first userid is user1 and I have updated it to user2. Will the MFP database store both the userids or will it replace user1 by user2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WL.Server.setActiveUser("AuthRealm", userIdentity);` **replaces** the current user identity in the server.

Comment: You mean to say it will never keep the previous userids(useridentities) .

Comment: Thanks for the reply.